# Confusing Function Output

Tags: php, function, date, if-statement, while-loop

I am really confused with the outcome of the following function. I know that its a small snippet of code but I think there is enough information to understand what is supposed to happen:

```
while ($k < $dateCount) {
        echo $k." ==> ".$forecastData[$k]['Booked Date']." ==> ".$startDate."<br>";
        if($forecastData[$k]['Booked Date'] == $startDate){
            echo $k." ==> YAY<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo $k." ==> boo ==> ".$startDate."<br>";
        }
        $k++;
        $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startDate)));
    }
```

**$k** is the array key -> starts at 0;

**$dateCount** is the size of the array (to stop it at the 31 days or however long the range is)

**$forecastData** is a multidimensional array of all sales data for a date. – contains loads of information for that date including the booked date which is the day the information is stored for.

**$startDate** is the date that has been put in but converted to the same day last year – in this case the date put in is Oct 01 2016 and the converted date is Sep 26 2015

I want to say that if the dates are equal then echo the number of the array with the word YAY otherwise echo the array number with the word boo.

The k increases by 1 per loop as does the date.

I have also printed the initial values of the loop to show me what the comparison is.

What I cant understand is that this is the output:

> 0 ==> 2015-09-26 ==> 2015-09-26
>
> 0 ==> boo ==> 2015-09-26
>
> 1 ==> 2015-09-27 ==> 2015-09-27
>
> 1 ==> YAY
>
> 2 ==> 2015-09-28 ==> 2015-09-28
>
> 2 ==> YAY
>
> 3 ==> 2015-09-29 ==> 2015-09-29
>
> 3 ==> YAY
>
> 4 ==> 2015-09-30 ==> 2015-09-30
>
> 4 ==> YAY
>
> 5 ==> 2015-10-01 ==> 2015-10-01
>
> 5 ==> YAY
>
> 6 ==> 2015-10-02 ==> 2015-10-02
>
> 6 ==> YAY
>
> 7 ==> 2015-10-03 ==> 2015-10-03
>
> 7 ==> YAY
>
> 8 ==> 2015-10-04 ==> 2015-10-04
>
> 8 ==> YAY
>
> 9 ==> 2015-10-05 ==> 2015-10-05
>
> 9 ==> YAY
>
> 10 ==> 2015-10-06 ==> 2015-10-06
>
> 10 ==> YAY
>
> 11 ==> 2015-10-07 ==> 2015-10-07
>
> 11 ==> YAY

The first one makes NO sense to me?? It does equal what it should but for some reason skips by it?? Also if I hardcode the date in then it will work.

I have been trying to understand this for so long now that any ideas will help

Thank you

Comment: try using `var_dump()` instead of echo for more detailed info (variable type etc.) - also: how do you define $startDate before entering the loop?

Comment: Guess: there's a trailing space or other invisible character on the first date string…

Comment: Show initial declaration of `$startDate`

Comment: I define start date by calling it from a function that converts it to a same day last year:

$startDate = $this->getLastYearDate($start);

I have done the var_dump() but all it says is that they are all strings. So it is ok because its comparing Strings to Strings? Is it because I don't set a $startDate but just call it straight from function?

Comment: How exactly did you check? If you use `var_dump`, pay special attention to the number next to "`string`"; it tells you how long your string really is. Is everything identical about both strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your output I see that highlighting `2015-09-26` also will select trailing white space while highlighting `2015-09-27` has no trailing space.

So it means `2015-09-26` != `2015-09-26_`. Use `trim($startDate)` or just check from where this trailing white space is coming.

Also when debugging it's better to use `var_dump($startDate); => string(11) "2015-09-26 "`. That way you will also see string length.

---

*From personal experience*
Was comparing `hello` to `hello` it it failed. Turns out `var_dump($var);` shows `hello` length as 10. Further investigation showed that it's `\0h\0e\0l\0l\0o`

Comment: Yeah thank you for this -- I did that as well and it did the same. I can't figure out why it did that when its getting the same thing each time?

Comment: damn. was my first thought, too, but couldn't confirm it. SO's formatting removed that trailing space, it was only visible when entering the edit-functionality.

Comment: @Andrew check your `$this->getLastYearDate($start)` if it introduces a space somewhere. probably a `date('Y-m-d ')` or something

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann Thank you -- I saw my error it was indeed returning a date with a space in it. I guess when the date was added by one it removed that and thats why it worked for the rest.

Thank you all so much for the help

Comment: @Andrew `strtotime` does it's job good and removes any other symbols that does not match date format